# My sweet alert2 butons are both submiting the delete form

Tags: javascript, laravel, sweetalert2

let me just start with stating that I don't understand javascript nor ajax
so I tried to follow a couple of codes in order to make an alert pop up before confirming the deletion of a reservation but even if I press cancel the reservation is deleted or even when I press in a random place the form is submitted, and since I don't understand the code very well I couldn't detect the problem can someone please tell me what i sould fix

here is my js code :

```
    <!-- SweetAlert2 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.2.0/sweetalert2.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.2.0/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    function confirmDelete(item_id) {
        swal({
            title: "Attention!",
            text: "Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir annuler votre réservation?",
            type: "warning",
            buttons: true,
            showCancelButton: !0,
            confirmButtonColor: '#FFC61A',
            confirmButtonText: "Oui!",
            cancelButtonText: "Annuler",
            dangerMode: true,
            reverseButtons: !0
        })
            .then((willDelete) => {
                if (willDelete) {
                    $('#delete-company').submit();

                }else {
                    swal("Cancelled Successfully");
                }
            });
    }
```

and here is my button and my form

```
    <td>
                                <form id="delete-company" action="{{ url('reservations/'.$r->id) }}" method="post">
                                    {{csrf_field()}}
                                    {{method_field('delete')}}
                                    <button type="button" class="btn  btn-black-bordered btn-xs" onclick="confirmDelete('delete-company')"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                                </form>
                                
                            </td>
```

and my controller

```
    public function destroy(Reservation $reservation)
{
    try {
        Reservation::where('id',$reservation->id)->delete();
        
        Alert::success('Succès', 'La réservation a été annulée avec succès')->autoClose(false);
        return back();
        
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return back()->withError('Une erreur est survenue, veuillez réessayer ultérieurement')->withInput();    
    }
}
```

update of my code after trying some suggestions

```
   <form id="{{'delete-company-'.$r->id}}" action="{{ url('reservations/'.$r->id) }}" method="post">
                                    {{csrf_field()}}
                                    {{method_field('delete')}}
                                </form>
                                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-black-bordered btn-xs" onclick="confirmDelete('{{$r->id}}')">
                                    <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                                 </button>
```

and here is my new Script

```
    <script>
    function confirmDelete(item_id) {
        swal({
            title: "Attention!",
            text: "Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir annuler votre réservation?",
            type: "warning",
            buttons: true,
            showCancelButton: !0,
            confirmButtonColor: '#FFC61A',
            confirmButtonText: "Oui!",
            cancelButtonText: "Annuler",
            dangerMode: true,
            reverseButtons: !0
        })
            .then((willDelete) => {
                if (willDelete) {
                    $('#delete-company-'+item_id).submit();
              

                }else {
                    swal("Cancelled Successfully");
                }
            });
    }
    </script>
```

and still,[image: the list of reservations] the box is showing but where ever I clique the form is still submitted

[image: sweet alert box]

Comment: I'd assume your button triggers a call to your controller, no matter if you have a popup confirmation or not.

Comment: no, the warning is showing first when I clique cancel or confirm button or anywhere the form is submitted

Answer (score 0):

With an alert in the middle of a submit, I usually move the trigger button outside a form.  Generally I don't even have a form.  I use the button to trigger SWAL.  SWAL asks if I want to do something, and then I use ajax to push the data to the server.

If you want to submit the form and not use ajax, I suggest you **move the button outside the form** and then submit using JS as you have in your questions.

Doing it without the form (remove the form, just grab the ID) might be cleanest though:

```
 function confirmDelete(item_id) {
    swal({
        title: "Attention!",
        text: "Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir annuler votre réservation?",
        type: "warning",
        buttons: true,
        showCancelButton: !0,
        confirmButtonColor: '#FFC61A',
        confirmButtonText: "Oui!",
        cancelButtonText: "Annuler",
        dangerMode: true,
        reverseButtons: !0
    })
        .then((willDelete) => {
            if (willDelete) {
                // AJAX here - push the id to your delete method

            }else {
                swal("Cancelled Successfully");
            }
        });
}
```

Also - you don't show if this is a looped form, but be careful if you are looping not to have the same form id / name over and over.

Comment: hello thank you for answering, unfortunately, i didn't get it as I said I m not good with javascript nor ajax that's why I have no idea how to do what you just told me so if you could just give me an example of your work so I could follow it since my code is wrong, and yes I am using a loop for my table each row is deletable.

Comment: Its not the JS that is the problem, it is the HTML.  1) The button is inside the form.  Move it outside.  2) The second problem is that you are overwriting the form `id` every time.  Change the form id to a variable to fix.  Something like `id="{{'delete-company-'.$r->id}}"`  Then use your original code, but remember to add the id to the JS to submit the form (`$('#delete-company-'+item_id).submit();`)This will solve the problem for you :)

Comment: You also need to push the id correctly into the JS function.  `onclick="confirmDelete('delete-company')"` every time doesn't work.  Same thing - add the id here instead `onclick="confirmDelete('{{$r->id}}')"`

Comment: Good evening, I'm sorry to tell you that your solution didn't solve my problem :/ I'm sure it's a js problem because the model always shows up but no matter where I clique my table always get deleted .

Comment: Did you try moving the button outside the form?  Did you change the IDs?  The issue is in the triggering of the JS, not the JS.  So the problem is in whatever is triggering the function, which is the HTML.  Did you try those things and it still failed?

Comment: yes i did let me show you my code once again

Comment: I have just updated the code above so you get to see what I've changed

Comment: OK, your code does look OK for the ID problem.  I suggest you get rid of the form altogether and just use the `then()` section of SWAL to AJAX the data over.  There is really no need for the form, since you have the ID you need to delete.  This will prevent the multiple submits.  But I would also recommend using the element to call the function.  IE `$(".classOfButton").on('click', function(){ ... }` to also narrow down the problem.  Instead of `onclick()` as this could also trigger mutlple times.

Comment: i tried some previous code with ajax but the box doesn't even show, is there something I should upload for the ajax to work? i have these 2 packages  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.2.0/sweetalert2.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.2.0/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>